# How to get one thread to wait for another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two threads: C and D.  If I want thread C to execute first, then thread D, that is what I must do:

This is code for class `ThreadC`:

```
public class ThreadC implements Runnable {

    int isi[] = new int[100];

    public void run () {
        for (int i = 0;i < isi.length; i++) {
            isi[i] = i;
            System.out.print(isi[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

This is code for class `ThreadD`:

```
public class ThreadD implements Runnable {

    int temp=0;

    public void run () {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            temp += i;
        System.out.println("nilai temp : " + temp);
    }
}
```

This is the main method:

```
public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ThreadC tc = new ThreadC();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tc);
        t1.start();
        ThreadD td = new ThreadD();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(td);
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I actually have the problem, that I have class. First I call ThreadC. I want thread C is completed execute then thread under for will be executed. Then I call ThreadD. It is like the code below:

```
for (int j = 0; j < idW.length; j++) {
    webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]); 
    ThreadPrepo tpo = new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j%jumhost], "server", 1099, idW[j]);  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tpo);
    t1.start();

}
ThreadD td = new ThreadD;
Thread t2 = new Thread(t2);
t2.start();
```

So ThreadD t2 will executed after thread t1 complete executed, so Thread t2 must wait until t1 hash finished.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Don't call it a thread if it is a `Runnable`. Synchronize your `run()` method code on a shared object between your two `Runnable` instances. The first one to enter the block will execute and complete first.

Comment: Why is it that the first thing everybody tries to do with threads is defeat the entire point of having threads in the first place?

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want sequential execution, why are you using threads at all?

Comment: My guess is that this is just a simplified example for something that's actually more complex, and there are multiple threads that actually need to run.

Comment: this is only example because i have class where in the process with multithread...and i want to the process in class where there are multhi thread is complete first (i mean like class with threadC) then program will accses code in class with ThreadD..so i asked like above...

Comment: Nevertheless there is no point in using two threads if the second one has to wait for the first one to finish. The two actions should be part of the same thread. Possibly what you're really looking for is some kind of sequential job scheduling system.

Comment: @EJP:yes,is similiar sequential job...my thread C will insert all data to table in my database...
after Thread C finished...
Thread D will select data from table is inserted by thread C...that's why i want thread C completed executed then thread b will executed after that
thanks for your comment and answer all.... i fell help

Comment: You may find that a [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) makes your life easier, but will require rethinking your design. Also check out the actors pattern [java-akka-example]( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/java/hello-world.html).  You should find these easier to scale and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). Joining on a thread will wait for it to complete. If you want `t2` to run after `t1`, the following snippet will do that:

```
t1.start();
t1.join(); // blocks until t1 is complete
t2.start();
```

EDIT: To clarify, if you really only have two threads like this, do not do this - threads are not needed and the runnables can just be run sequentially. The join works well if you have multiple threads running concurrently and you need to wait for all of them to finish before running some other code (the code after the threads finish does not need to be run in a thread).

Comment: I agree. I was answering the question asked. In this case, if you really just had two threads like this, why use threads at all. But, if you wanted to wait for multiple threads before continuing.

Comment: this is only example because i have class where in the process with multithread...and i want to the process in class where there are multhi thread is complete first (i mean like class with threadC)  then program will accses code in class with ThreadD..so i asked like above...

Comment: i have try to use t1.join()..and then the ThreadD will wait until Thread C completed proceses...thanks for your comment and answer all....
i fell help....
any another solution please....

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeff's answer, java.util.concurrent has lots of options.

CountDownLatch or Semaphore would achieve that.  Using Runnables, you could use a threadPoolExecutor, with a thread pool size of one.

If you don't want them to run concurrently, it probably makes sense to only create one thread

For example, using a thread pool executor

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(new ThreadC());
executor.execute(new ThreadD());
```

Comment: can u give example with code @Edh so i will more understad..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads at all. Just run your Runnables in the desired order:

```
    ThreadC tc=new ThreadC();
    tc.run();
    ThreadD td=new ThreadD();
    td.run();
```

Comment: But if he really wants to execute the code in separate thread then what?

Comment: @user1590011 Then, err, obviously, don't do this. He hasn't convinced me yet. What he really wants is D to execute after C. I can't see why running them both in a single thread wouldn't satisfy that requirement.